# Why Spring Boot is not finding a @Service bean trying to perform autowiring? the bean exist but it can't find it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am experiencing a strange problem working on a **Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE** project that uses **JUnit**.

I try to explain my problem in details:

1) I defined a service. First I defined an interface named **OrderService**, like this:

```
package com.dgs.soc.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.dgs.soc.excelapi.dto.Order;

public interface OrderService {

    public List<Order> getOrdersList();

}
```

Then I defined its implementation, at the moment something very simple named **OrderServiceImpl**:

```
package com.dgs.soc.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.dgs.soc.excelapi.dto.Order;
import com.dgs.soc.repository.OrderRepository;

@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl {

    public List<Order> getOrdersList() {
        List<Order> result = new ArrayList<Order>();

        return result;
    }

}
```

As you can see this class is annoted by the **@Service** annotation.

The problem is using **JUnit**, I have this test class:

```
package com.dgs.soc.excelapi.integration;

// IMPORTS LIST

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "no-liquibase" })
public class ExcelResourceIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    OrderServiceImpl orderService;

    @Test
    public void getOrdersListRepositoryTest() { 
        List<Order> ordersList = orderService.getOrdersList();
        assertThat(ordersList).isNotEmpty();
    }

}
```

And here I am experiencing a strange behavior: performing the **getOrdersListRepositoryTest()** test method I obtain this exception

```
2020-03-23 04:42:24.783 ERROR 5281 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7fbdb894] to prepare test instance [com.dgs.soc.excelapi.integration.ExcelResourceIntegrationTest@2ad6895a]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.dgs.soc.excelapi.integration.ExcelResourceIntegrationTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'orderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dgs.soc.service.OrderServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40) ~[junit-vintage-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80) ~[junit-vintage-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71) ~[junit-vintage-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210) ~[.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dgs.soc.service.OrderServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted

2020-03-23 04:42:24.816  INFO 5281 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-23 04:42:24.819  INFO 5281 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-23 04:42:24.846  INFO 5281 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-23 04:42:24.875  INFO 5281 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

It says that **No qualifying bean of type 'com.dgs.soc.service.OrderServiceImpl' available** but, as you can see in the prevuous code this bean exist and it is annoted by the **@Service** annotation to allow autowiring !!!

Into this project there is defined a class annotated by **@RestController** that exposes API. If into this class I try to autowire the same service class, something like this:

```
@Description(value = "Resource layer for handling REST requests.")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class ExcelResource {

    @Autowired
    OrderServiceImpl orderService;

    .......................................................
    .......................................................
    .......................................................
}
```

and now I try to perform the application as **Spring Boot Application** I obtain the same problem:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field orderService in com.dgs.soc.excelapi.resources.ExcelResource required a bean of type 'com.dgs.soc.service.OrderServiceImpl' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.dgs.soc.service.OrderServiceImpl' in your configuration.
```

But again the **com.dgs.soc.service.OrderServiceImpl** bean exist and it is annotated by **@Service**.

Why am I obtaining this issue? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this problem? I was thinking that I have some references problem or something like this but I have no idea

**EDIT-1:**
Putting the **@ComponentScan("com.dgs.soc.service")** on the topo of my **Application** class it seems to work but I have some doubts !!!

So this is my **Application** class now:

```
package com.dgs.soc.excelapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.dgs.soc.service")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

It works but int thwory it should works also without the **    @ComponentScan("com.dgs.soc.service")** annotation because this class was annoted by **@SpringBootApplication** that as you can read here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.12.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

automatically enable @ComponentScan: @Component scan on the package where the application is located (see the best practices)

So the application is located into **com.dgs.soc.excelapi** and in theory I expected that the component scan have to work popperly also withot the explicit defntion of **@ComponentScan**

Why? Some idea?

Comment: In what package is your `Application` class? Generally spring only auto-scans the package where the `Application`class resides and any of its child package. Try adding explicit list of packages to scan on the `Application` class.

Comment: May be you don't have the Spring loader scan that package where we have your serviceClass Implementation, may be you can try to use @ComponentScan("<package-name>")

Comment: @Setu My Application class is into the "com.dgs.soc.excelapi" package

Comment: @AndreaNobili in that case you definitely need to explicitly scan the packages. You can use `ComponentScan` annotation on spring boot application class or provide `scanBasePackages` attribute on the `SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: @Setu in this way works, I added some new info at the end of my original post because in theory it should work also without the use of **ComponentScan** because I am using **SpringBootApplication** annotation. What am I missing?

Comment: Put your `Application` class in `com.dgs.soc` package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you do not have proper package structure for spring-boot auto scan to pick up your service class.

`SpringBootApplication` annotation only enabled scanning of the package it resides in and its child packages.

If you have `SpringBootApplication` class in `com.acme.app` package then all the classes with spring boot annotation will get scanned in the package `com.acme.app` and any of its child packages i.e. `com.acme.app.services`, `com.acme.app.controllers`, etc. However if you have a package `com.acme.services` then any spring annotations are not auto-scanned from this package.

You have two options;

- You either modify your package structure to allow spring-boot to auto scan all of the annotations. In your case move your `Application` class from `com.dgs.soc.excelapi` to `com.dgs.soc`. Or you could move all other packages i.e. service under `com.dgs.soc.excelapi`.
- You explicitly list packages to scan using either @ComponentScan or `scanBasePackages` attribute on the `SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: Ahhh ok, and what is the neater solution for you?

Comment: dude, you have saved my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Try putting `@ComponentScan` annotation on top of main application class

```
@ComponentScan("base.package.name")
```

Comment: In this way works but in theory it have to work also without the use of **ComponentScan** annotation because I am use **SpringBootApplication** annotation on my Application class. I added some additional info at the end of my original post. What am I missing?

Comment: If you want it work without @ComponentScan, then all other packages must be sub packages of com.dgs.soc.excelapi ex. com.dgs.soc.excelapi.service, com.dgs.soc.excelapi.dao or all classes could be in same package as of main application class

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the following:

Your Application class is in package "com.dgs.soc.excelapi"

@SpringBootApplication scans **that package + all its subpackages** for @Services/@Components/@Repositories.

You put all your services in completely different packages though ("com.dgs.soc.service"), so Spring Boot won't find them. And hence the @ComponentScan annotation works.

**Fix**: Reorder your package structure.